# Play folder content in Audacious on right click in Thunar

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, audacious

I would like to add a custom action in thunar, playing a content of a folder in Audacious. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Edit > configure custom actions`, click the + button, for name type whatever you want, for command type `audacious %F`. You can select the icon if you want. Go to appearance conditions and select only `Directories`. Click OK and now you can now right click any folder and this action will appear in the context menu.